# Out-GridView return full objects while displaying only selected properties

Tags: powershell

I have an array of hashtables to process and need the user to select one or more of them for further processing. I can get the GridView to display them correctly however I need to be able to display only 3 or 4 properties which will allow the end user to pick the correct entries and hide the rest from display.

The returned object should be the whole hashtable.

```
$t = @{}
$t.Name = "Test"
$t.URL = "http://xxx.test"
$t.Type = "UAT" 
$RptServers = ,$t

$p = @{}
$p.Name = "Prod-MEL"
$p.URL = "http://xxx.Prod"
$p.Type = "PROD" 
$RptServers += $p

$selectedSSRS = $RptServers | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ | Select-Object -Property 'Name','Type' } | Out-GridView -Title "Select Report Server(s)" -PassThru
$selectedSSRS
```

If the user selects Test the object returned has these properties:

```
Name Type
---- ----
Test UAT
```

However I would like to have the whole object with URL, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think that I found a possible solution, however it is not very elegant and would prefer a 'one-liner'

```
$temp = $RptServers | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select-Object -Property 'Name','Type' } | Out-GridView -Title "Select Report Server(s)" -PassThru
$selectedSSRS = $RptServers | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $temp.Name }
$selectedSSRS
```

The Where-Object clause will need tweaking in actual code as just Name might not be unique enough to ensure only the correct entries are added to the selected list

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines of your script to this three lines:

```
$selectedSSRS = $RptServers | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ }    
$selectedSSRS | Select-Object -Property 'Name','Type' | Out-GridView -Title "Select Report Server(s)" 
$selectedSSRS
```

The Select-Object filter is only effective on the gridview here, while $selectedSSRS has all properties

Comment: The aim is to allow the user to select items to be added to the `$selectedSSRS`. Your solution adds all object to the variable first and then displays using GridView without the selection ability. If I add the -`PassThrough` it allows to select once again however it output is still the same as above (and it does not get saved in the `$selectedSSRS` variable

Comment: I get it now. I think your solution is OK. In this case it would be nice if there was an option to determine the properties displayed by Out-Gridview, without disposing them.

Answer (score 0):

One liners can be elegant but cumbersome to maintain. Still, I'm here nearly four years after the fact to give this to anyone who would come here for the same reasons as me and might find it useful:

```
$t = [pscustomobject]@{Name = "Test";URL = "http://xxx.test";Type = "UAT"}
$p = [pscustomobject]@{Name = "Prod-MEL";URL = "http://xxx.Prod";Type = "PROD" }
$RptServers = $t,$p

$selectedSSRS = $RptServers | Where Name -in ($RptServers | Select-Object -Property Name,Type | Out-GridView -Title "Select Report Server(s)" -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
```

Note that for it to work, you need to have an array of objects beforehand, not build the pscustomobjects on the fly.